# How to define `name` and `inheritAttrs` in `<script setup>`?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

Options API:

```html
<script>
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'CustomName', // 
    inheritAttrs: false, // 
    setup() {
      return {}
    },
  })
</script>
```

How to do that in `<script setup>`, is there an equivalent for `name` and `inheritAttrs` like `defineProps` and `defineEmits`?

```html
<script setup>
  //  how to define them here?
</script>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

With Vue ^3.3, you can now use [`defineOptions()`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineoptions) directly:

```html
<script setup>
  defineOptions({
    name: 'CustomName',
    inheritAttrs: false,
    customOptions: {},
  })
</script>
```

---

The `<script setup>` syntax provides the ability to express equivalent functionality of most existing Options API options except for a few:

- `name`
- `inheritAttrs`
- Custom options needed by plugins or libraries

If you need to declare these options, there're two ways:

1. If using Vue Macros, you can use [`defineOptions()`](https://vue-macros.sxzz.moe/macros/define-options.html), this might be the most succinct approach:

```html
<script setup>
  defineOptions({
    name: 'CustomName',
    inheritAttrs: false,
    customOptions: {},
  })
</script>
```

2. If you don't want to rely on external libraries, you can use a separate normal `<script>` block with `export default`:

```html
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'CustomName',
    inheritAttrs: false,
    customOptions: {},
  }
</script>

<script setup>
  // script setup logic
</script>
```

Compiled output:

```html
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'CustomName',
    inheritAttrs: false,
    customOptions: {},
    setup() {
      // script setup logic
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a more elegant way to define a component name?

Comment: @AlexanderKim When you use Single-File Components, the component already infers its name from the filename, the `name` option allows you to override the inferred name, I don't know if there's any other way.

Comment: I think the most elegant solution is to just rename the component file name. e.g., instead of Header.vue, rename it MainHeader.vue, or HeaderView.vue. You may have some refactoring, but there would be no need for a separate <script> tag.

Comment: Link to the docs: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script

Answer (score 2):

there is a vite plugin [vite-plugin-vue-setup-extend](https://github.com/vbenjs/vite-plugin-vue-setup-extend) can resolve set component name.

#### config

```
// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import VueSetupExtend from 'vite-plugin-vue-setup-extend'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    VueSetupExtend()
  ]
})
```

#### usage

```
<script lang="ts" setup name="CompName">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defineComponent` like this if you want to use `setup` script and typescript:

```
<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  inheritAttrs: false,
});
</script>
<script setup lang="ts">
// Your setup code
</script>
```

In Vue 3.3 and later, You can define `defineOptions` inside `setup script`:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
defineOptions({
  inheritAttrs: false
})
</script>
```

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: @JoeMaffei please check my code now, I've tested this one and this worked for me

Comment: The code you provided isn't inside the `setup` script, but your answer says we can.

Comment: sure, This way is for using `setup script` and `typescript` @SamHoque

Answer (score -1):

You can use [unplugin-vue-define-options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unplugin-vue-define-options) to define options API within `<script setup>`

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { computed } from "vue";
import { useWindowScroll } from "@vueuse/core";

defineOptions({ name: "BackToTop" });

const { y: scrollY } = useWindowScroll();

const show = computed(() => scrollY.value > 180);
</script>
```